# how can i merge two nested list as dictionary?

Tags: python, function

I've been trying to understand how this problem works but i don't know how to merge two nested list into a dictionary.

I need to create a function combine (). If I have a nested list called info and i have  another nested list called detail. i need to combine these two nested list as a dictionary and returns the dictionary.  I don't quite actually know how to start my code. As I don't actually know how to merge a nested list as dictionary.

```
info = [["Kean", 36, "Comp Sci", "Dept 2"], ["Ethan", 24, "Engineer", "Dept 5"], ["Kin", 23, "Med Tech", "Dept 1"]]
detail = [("Kean", ['good', "very good", "pass"]), ("Ethan", ["fail", "good", "fail"])]
```

the output should look like this:

```
{"Kean": [["Kean", 36, "Comp Sci", "Dept 2"], ['good', "very good", "pass"]], 'Ethan': [["Ethan", 24, "Engineer", "Dept 5"], ["fail", "good", "fail"]]}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Your approach?

Comment: I just tried to merge the lists but it didnt work i just didnt get how can i merge those nested lists as a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only matching names should be merged (as seen in the intended output of OP). This would work.

```
info = [["Kean", 36, "Comp Sci", "Dept 2"], ["Ethan", 24, "Engineer", "Dept 5"], ["Kin", 23, "Med Tech", "Dept 1"]]
detail = [("Kean", ['good', "very good", "pass"]), ("Ethan", ["fail", "good", "fail"])]

outdict = {}

for i in info:    
    nameInfo = i[0]
    for j in detail:
        nameDetail = j[0]
        if nameDetail == nameInfo:
            outdict[nameDetail] = [i, j[1]]
            
print(outdict)
```

Output:

```
{'Kean': [['Kean', 36, 'Comp Sci', 'Dept 2'], ['good', 'very good', 'pass']], 'Ethan': [['Ethan', 24, 'Engineer', 'Dept 5'], ['fail', 'good', 'fail']]}
```

Sidenote; this could be done a lot more efficiently in terms of processing time. But for a small sample size, as is asked in the original question, this works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
info = [["Kean", 36, "Comp Sci", "Dept 2"], ["Ethan", 24, "Engineer", "Dept 5"], ["Kin", 23, "Med Tech", "Dept 1"]]
detail = [("Kean", ['good', "very good", "pass"]), ("Ethan", ["fail", "good", "fail"])]
for key, *value in info + detail:
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Ethan': [[24, 'Engineer', 'Dept 5'], [['fail', 'good', 'fail']]],
 'Kean': [[36, 'Comp Sci', 'Dept 2'], [['good', 'very good', 'pass']]],
 'Kin': [[23, 'Med Tech', 'Dept 1']]}
```

---

You can also use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for key, *value in info + detail:
    result[key].append(value)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'Ethan': [[24, 'Engineer', 'Dept 5'], [['fail', 'good', 'fail']]],
             'Kean': [[36, 'Comp Sci', 'Dept 2'],
                      [['good', 'very good', 'pass']]],
             'Kin': [[23, 'Med Tech', 'Dept 1']]})
```

Comment: This does not corrospond with the original posters expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
info = [["Kean", 36, "Comp Sci", "Dept 2"], ["Ethan", 24, "Engineer", "Dept 5"], ["Kin", 23, "Med Tech", "Dept 1"]]
detail = [("Kean", ['good', "very good", "pass"]), ("Ethan", ["fail", "good", "fail"])]

result={element[0]:[element] for element in info}
```

This will give you a dictionary with name as the key and info as value

```
for name in detail:
    if name[0] in result.keys():
        result[name[0]].append(name[1])
print(result)
```

What we did was to check for names in result's key and to append the detail in it's values.

```
{'Kean': [['Kean', 36, 'Comp Sci', 'Dept 2'], ['good', 'very good', 'pass']], 'Ethan': [['Ethan', 24, 'Engineer', 'Dept 5'], ['fail', 'good', 'fail']], 'Kin': [['Kin', 23, 'Med Tech', 'Dept 1']]}
```

I find it much easier!